# 5 band resistor - value, watt and tolerance

Tags: resistors

My 700 watt EVGA power supply has stopped working.  I think a resistor has gone bad. The resistor has 5 bands - brown, green, grey/silver, gold, green.  I would appreciate if someone can tell me its ohm, watt and tolerance.

[image]

Comment: Here's a calculator: https://circuitdigest.com/calculators/5-band-resistor-color-code-calculator -- looks like 15.8 ohms +- 0.5%

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a 0.15 ohm resistor with a 5% tolerance and a 20ppm/K temperature coefficient. But I'm not 100% certain due to the range of resistor coding systems.
From the size I estimate it to have a 2 watt rating.

As it looks in pretty bad shape, don't just replace the resistor - try and find out what caused this.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code

Comment: 5 bands means 3digit, so at least 1%.

Comment: True, but silver is generally not a digit colour and I don't think that can be grey

Comment: So, if the 5-band marking not fit your concept, just ignore one band. Either the tolerance mark is 1% or O.5%.

Comment: that should be 0.15Ohm 0.5%